# Split string in two parts by length

Tags: java

How to split a string in two parts : one part with first three characters & another part with leftover characters ?

(I finally need to convert both splitted substrings to Bytebuffers).

Comment: Have a look at the [API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), especially the `substring(...)` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn a sub string String into a byte buffer

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(myString.substring(0,3).getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String part1 = myString.substring(0,3);
String part2 = myString.substring(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression for splitting strings by segment length.

```
String[] splitInput(String inputString, int segmentSize) {
    String re = "(?<=\\G.{" + segmentSize + "})";
    return inputString.split(re);
}
```

-- demonstrated below --

```
> splitInput("foobarfoobar", 1)
String[12] { "f", "o", "o", "b", "a", "r", "f", "o", "o", "b", "a", "r" }

> splitInput("foobarfoobar", 3)
String[4] { "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar" }

> splitInput("foobarfoobar", 5)
String[3] { "fooba", "rfoob", "ar" }

> splitInput("foobarfoobar", 10000)
String[1] { "foobarfoobar" }
```