# How can I extract a floating point number from a string efficiently?

Tags: java

If there is:

```
String s="0.0234000ETH";
```

What is one of the **most efficient/better** ways to **isolate** the floating part so that:

```
float result=0.0234000;  //or just 0.0234
```

Keep in mind I do not care loosing the `String` part (ETH in this case).

Comment: Are the numeric and/or character parts always of the same length?

Comment: @mustaccio yes, the same length, both the numbers and the letters

Comment: [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120413/split-string-in-two-parts-by-length)

Comment: @mustaccio That did solve it

Comment: if `ETH` is "fixed" then `Float.valueOf(String s)`  *should* be the most efficient in java, (otherwise/) regex can also perform well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
        float number = Float.parseFloat(s.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
        System.out.println(number);
```

Or, what's already mentioned in the comments:
Get the substring which only contains the number. Then you can parse it to your data type.

```
        String s = "0.0234000ETH";
        String part1 = s.substring(0,8);
        float value = Float.parseFloat(part1);
        System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: This did the job